# Set Antlr4 custom generation path relative to project root?

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr4

Using the [Antlr4 intellij plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358?pr=).  I want to customise the directory into which Antlr puts generated code.  Right-Clicking the grammar file and selecting `Configure Antlr...` enables this: `Output directory where all output is generated`.  However: it's an absolute path.

That breaks project portability, e.g. can't work on the project across linux & windows machines.

**So: is there a way to enter the generation path relative to the module root?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I programmatically put the files into one of my packages using the ***org.antlr.v4.Tool*** as below:

`Tool.main(new String[]{"MyGrammar.g4", "-o", "src/com/package/files/"});`

Running this generates the Lexer, Parser, and the Listeners in the specified folder.
My grammar file is located in the root of my project like */home/workspae/MyProject/MyGrammar.g4* and my *Main()* is with the above command is in a different package folder.